# Next Time Of Given Pattern

Tags: code-golf, date, pattern-matching

### Introduction:

Some times using a 24-hour clock are formatted in a nice pattern. For these patterns, we'll have four different categories:

```
All the same (pattern A:AA or AA:AA):
 0:00
 1:11
 2:22
 3:33
 4:44
 5:55
11:11
22:22
```

```
Increasing (pattern B:CD or AB:CD, where D==C+1==B+2==A+3):
 0:12
 1:23
 2:34
 3:45
 4:56
12:34
23:45
```

```
Pair (pattern AB:AB):
10:10
12:12
13:13
14:14
15:15
16:16
17:17
18:18
19:19
20:20
21:21
23:23
```

```
Palindrome (pattern A:BA or AB:BA):
 0:10
 0:20
 0:30
 0:40
 0:50
 1:01
 1:21
 1:31
 1:41
 1:51
 2:02
 2:12
 2:32
 2:42
 2:52
 3:03
 3:13
 3:23
 3:43
 3:53
 4:04
 4:14
 4:24
 4:34
 4:54
 5:05
 5:15
 5:25
 5:35
 5:45
 6:06
 6:16
 6:26
 6:36
 6:46
 6:56
 7:07
 7:17
 7:27
 7:37
 7:47
 7:57
 8:08
 8:18
 8:28
 8:38
 8:48
 8:58
 9:09
 9:19
 9:29
 9:39
 9:49
 9:59
10:01
12:21
13:31
14:41
15:51
20:02
21:12
23:32
```

### Challenge:

Given a starting time and a category, output how many minutes should be added to the start time, for it to reach the closest (forward) time of the given category.

*For example:* if the start time is `14:47` and the category is `palindrome`, the smallest time after `14:47` in the palindrome category is `15:51`, so the output is `64` minutes (because 14:47 + 64 minutes = 15:51).

### Challenge Rules:

- As you may have noted: the times in the 'All the same' category are excluded from the 'Pair' and 'Palindrome' categories, even though they are technically also pairs/palindromes.
- We only look forward when we go to the closest time. So in the example above the output is `64` (time `15:51`) and not `-6` (time `14:41`).
- You may take the times in any reasonable format. May be a string, a (Date)Time-object, a pair of integers, etc.
- You may use any *reasonable* distinct input-values for the four categories. (Keep in mind [this forbidden loophole](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14110/52210)!) May be four integers; may be the category-names as strings; may be an enum; etc.
- If the input-time is already valid for the given category, the result is `0` (so we won't look for the next one).
- We use an `A:BC` pattern for single-digit hours, so they won't be left-padded with a `0` to `0A:BC`.

### General Rules:

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes wins.
  Don't let code-golf languages discourage you from posting answers with non-codegolfing languages. Try to come up with an as short as possible answer for 'any' programming language.
- [Standard rules apply](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet/2422#2422) for your answer with [default I/O rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/), so you are allowed to use STDIN/STDOUT, functions/method with the proper parameters and return-type, full programs. Your call.
- [Default Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- If possible, please add a link with a test for your code (e.g. [TIO](https://tio.run/#)).
- Also, adding an explanation for your answer is highly recommended.

### Test Cases:

You don't need to output the time between parenthesis. Those are just added as clarification in the test cases below. Only the integer-output is required to be output.

```
Inputs: 14:47, palindrome
Output: 64   (15:51)

Inputs: 0:00, all the same
Output: 0    (0:00)

Inputs: 23:33, palindrome
Output: 37   (0:10)

Inputs: 23:24, pair
Output: 646  (10:10)

Inputs: 10:00, increasing
Output: 154  (12:34)

Inputs: 0:00, increasing
Output: 12   (0:12)

Inputs: 23:59, all the same
Output: 1    (0:00)

Inputs: 11:11, pair
Output: 61   (12:12)
```

Comment: "Don't let code-golf languages discourage you from posting answers with non-codegolfing languages." That's exactly what discourages to post answers. Opinions aside, can you provide a few test cases of expected outputs? Also, you have "May be four integers; may be the category-names as strings; may be an enum; etc." but then you say "We use an `A:BC` pattern for single-digit hours, so they won't be left-padded with a `0` to `0A:BC`.". Does this mean the input, as numbers, has to be `[0,1,2,3]` or `[1,2,3]` for a time of `"1:23"` as a string? Or I'm mixing stuff up?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel "_can you provide a few test cases of expected outputs?_" There are 6 test cases at the bottom.. Any suggested test case I should add? And for input as numbers, I meant it as a pair of `[hours,minutes]` (or two loose `hours` and `minutes` inputs) - e.g. `[1,23]` instead of `1:23`. Although I guess `[1,2,3]` instead of `1:23` is valid as well if you want.

Comment: I started to write the comment before your edit. But I got distracted and only finished it later. Didn't notice the edit after submitting. Can we assume that all inputs are valid? Also, a test case could be `23:59`. Does it output `0:00` (1) for "all the same" and `0:10` (11) for "palindrome"? Or it isn't supposed to wrap around?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Yes, you can assume the input will always be valid. It's kinda an implicit rule for challenges, unless validation is part of the challenge. And yes, it does wrap around, and would indeed output `1` for `23:59, all the same` and `11` for `23:59, palindrome`. From the existing test cases, `23:33, palindrome` and `23:24, pair` cover wrap around as well. But I'll add that first suggested test case if it makes you happy. 

Comment: It actually makes no difference for me. It's just that 23:59 is a bit more explicit. The current list you have seems to be more than good enough.

Comment: Suggested test case: `11:11, pair ~> 61`.

Comment: @JonathanAllan `10:10, pair` should return 0, but `11:11, pair` should return 61 (which is why I suggested to add that one).

Comment: Ah, makes sense @Arnauld :)

Comment: @Arnauld Changed the title ('Time Patterns' was too short).

Answer (score 5):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 82 bytes

```
L+%/b60 24%"%02d"%b60JiQ60KE-f@[q1l{yT!-.+CMyT1&%%T60 11q.*cyT2&%%T60 11q_yTyT)KJJ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/30dbVT/JzEDByERVSdXAKEVJFcjzygw0M/B21U1ziC40zKmuDFHU1dN29q0MMVRTVQ0BqjY0LNTTSq4MMULw4ytDKkM0vb28/v@PNjTUUTA0iOUyAgA)

A bit ham fisted, but it works. Expects time as an integer list [hours, minutes] and type as (ALL, INC, PAI, PAL) -> (0, 1, 2, 3)

#### Explanation

```
L+%/b60 24%"%02d"%b60                                                                 define y(b) to format a number of seconds to the string "(h)hmm"
                     JiQ60                                                            set J to the input time as a number of seconds
                          KE                                                          set K to the input mode
                            -                                                    J    subtract the input time from
                             f                                                  J     the first integer greater than or equal to the input which satisfies
                              @[                                              )K      mode selection
                                q1l{yT                                                formatted string only has one unique character (all)
                                      !-.+CMyT1                                       code point deltas are all 1 (inc)
                                               &%%T60 11q.*cyT2                       string splits into two equal parts but seconds are not 0 mod 11 (pai)
                                                               &%%T60 11q_yTyT        string is the same as itself backwards but seconds are not 0 mod 11 (pal)
```

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 126 bytes

*-2 bytes thanks to [Kevin](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen)*

Expects `(type)(minutes, hours)`, with type in \$[0..3]\$ (*all the same*, *increasing*, *pair* and *palindrome* respectively).

```javascript
t=>g=(m,h,T=10,d=m-h)=>[q=m%11|d&&d-h*T,d-12-T*(282%h^6?h:1),h<T|d,(h>9?m/T^h%T?T:h/T:h)^m%T][t]|!q*t&&1+g(m=-~m%60,(h+!m)%24)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZFRa8IwFIXf@yuuDy2J3tomrXXqUpGxB0HGHvJWKojVZsPYqWFPsr/eNa0T93DhkI9zTm7yufneXLbnjy/jH6tiV@9FbURaCqJRoRQsxEJoX1GRZiehXcauhecVvupLLHzGfdkn/Im7ap3M1ZRRVM/yWiBR6WSuA7lWrpzLqQqaoWvtyjwz@bV36hvPY4OSaOH/aDcJG8Ogp6nLY1pvq@PFwGK1AgEhwvLtpREM4X2xbAS3wqJo5jizzAHIgMUI8bgDOUIQQBK3wPrt2LAOhO05jxCi6NEQje@Ax13XX1LSddyi7HU6wkb/Sx4Iv4eNJo/trItqlmG3hXJoS5iTO8N9dX7dbBUhGSgEjWAgpyBSsC9SHXbDQ1WSPTG0@RtQlNL6Fw)

### How?

All formulae are falsy if the criterion is met, or truthy if it's not.

If the first test is triggered, the other ones are forced to fail (this is `| !q * t` in the code). This enforces the rule about discarding pairs and palindromes with a unique digit.

#### All the same

```javascript
m % 11 | m - h && m - h * 11
```

We must have either:

- \$m\bmod 11=0\$ and \$m=h\$ (e.g. 22:22)
- or \$m=h\times11\$ (e.g. 4:44)

#### Increasing

```javascript
m - h - 12 - 10 * (282 % h ^ 6 ? h : 1)
```

We must have either:

- \$m=h+12+10\$ if \$h\in\{12,23\}\$
- or \$m=h+12+10\times h\$ if \$h\notin\{12,23\}\$

We have \$282\bmod h=6\$ if \$h\in\{12,23\}\$ and \$282\bmod h\neq 6\$ otherwise.

#### Pair

```javascript
h < 10 | h - m
```

We must have \$h\ge9\$ and \$h=m\$.

#### Palindrome

```javascript
(h > 9 ? m / 10 ^ h % 10 ? 10 : h / 10 : h) ^ m % 10
```

We must have either:

- \$h=m\bmod 10\$ if \$h\le 9\$
- or \$\lfloor m/10\rfloor = h\bmod 10\$ and \$\lfloor h/10\rfloor = m\bmod 10\$ if \$h>9\$

Comment: [129 bytes](https://tio.run/##VZHBbsIwDIbvfQpzKEogpXVayoClCE0ckNC0e1UkxIBsInRANOVQ7dW7pGWIHSw5/uL/t5PPzffmur18fOngVL7v6r2otcgOgigmmREYUZHlZ6F8xEoFskdkNq4qRMrsKUAemB7hT9yX63QmJ7Ysn00lA8XcxZkKzVr6ZmYmMrRB18o3Ra6LqnPu6W4X@weiRPCj/DSyDf2Ooj5PaL0tT1cN89UKBEQMlq8vNkEGb/OlTbhLHIqnnjfNPYAcMGGQjFpQMAhDSJMGuH4XTqwFUVPnMYM4fmyIR3fAk9brTyltPW5SbpyW4PC/yQPhd7Hh@NEdWym7DN4WKqAxQa/wBvvysthsJSE5SAaKgYaCgsjAvUh53A2O5YHsiab2e0BSSutf) by creating a variable for the seven occurrences of `10`. Nice answer btw!

Comment: your inequality symbols seem backwards in the pair and palindrome explanations, but im not sure

Comment: @thejonymyster The explanations tell what we must have for a valid pattern. On the other hand, as mentioned at the very beginning of the explanation, the code is _thuthy_ when the pattern is _invalid_. (For instance, `!(h<10|h-m)` is equivalent to `h>=9&h==m`.)

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 33 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
,_J$;,Ṛ,ŒHƲE€i1
“ð©½‘ḶŒpDF€ṙ⁸Ç€i’
```

A dyadic link that accepts the time of day in minutes as an integer on the left and the category as an integer on the right and yields the number of minutes until the clock will show a time with the given category.

| category | input value |
| --- | --- |
| all the same | 1 |
| increasing | 2 |
| palindrome | 3 |
| pair | 4 |

(Zero will give the time until no category too.)

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/18n3kvFWufhzlk6Ryd5HNvk@qhpTaYh16OGOYc3HFp5aO@jhhkPd2w7OqnAxQ0o83DnzEeNOw63gxQ9apj5//9/M3PD/yYA)** Or see the [test-suite](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/18n3kvFWufhzlk6Ryd5HNvk@qhpTaYh16OGOYc3HFp5aO@jhhkPd2w7OqnAxQ0o83DnzEeNOw63gxQ9apj5/@GORQ93Ln7UMNcq7OGOVjODw8sf7lwF1JuYk6NQkpGqUJyYmwrkZuYlF6UmFmfmpQM5BYk5mXkpRflgmYLEzCKg9sxjXZr//0dHqxuaWJmYq@soqCNUqcdy6USrG1gZGIDEkU2GyBgZWxkbY9MClDAygUhkFkGEDGHGIFyEajy6ONAMU0vs9hoaWhkaIhkfCwA).

#### How?

```
,_J$;,Ṛ,ŒHƲE€i1 - Helper Link = categorise: Time as a list of three or four digits
   $            - last two links as a monad - f(Time):
  J             -   range of length (Time) -> [1,2,3] or [1,2,3,4]
 _              -   (Time) subtract (that) (vectorises)
,               - (Time) pair with (that)
          Ʋ     - last four links as a monad - f(Time):
      Ṛ         -   reverse (Time)
     ,          -   (Time) pair with (that)
        ŒH      -   split (Time) into two halves
       ,        -   ([Time, Reversed(Time)]) pair (that)
    ;           - concatenate
                  -> [Time, Time - Indices, [Time, Reversed(Time)], [Prefix, Suffix]]
            €   - for each:
           E    -   all equal? -> 1 or 0
             i1 - first 1-indexed index of 1, or 0 if none

“ð©½‘ḶŒpDF€ṙ⁸Ç€i’ - Link = time to next: time of day in minutes, M; category, C
“ð©½‘             - code-page indicies = [24,6,10]
     Ḷ            - lowered range -> [[0..23],[0..5],[0..9]]
      Œp          - Cartesian product -> [[0,0,0],...,[0,5,9],[1,0,0],...,[23,5,9]]
        D         - digits -> [...,[[2,3],[5],[9]]]
         F€       - flatten each -> [[0,0,0],...,[0,5,9],[1,0,0],...,[2,3,5,9]]
           ṙ⁸     - rotate (that) left by (M)
             Ç€   - call the helper Link (above) for each
               i  - first 1-indexed index of (C) in (that) 
                ’ - decrement
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 73 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
@V¥[_e¥0}_e¥J}_ä+ e[TT]}_Î¥ZÌn «Zx}]b!gUì60_+60²+XÃÅvu24 gJ,_s ù'02Ã¬ä-}a
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=QFalW19lpTB9X2WlSn1f5CsgZVtUVF19X86lWsxuIKtaeH1dYiFnVew2MF8rNjCyK1jDxXZ1MjQgZ0osX3Mg%2bScwMsOs5C19YQ&input=WzIzLDMzXSwz)

Input is `[hours, minutes], pattern` with `pattern` in the range [0...3] using the same order as they are listed in the question.

#### Explanation:

Broad overview:

```
@                 }a # Find the smallest X that returns true:
           Uì...ä-   #  Calculate the time after X minutes and do some preprocessing
   [...]b!g          #  Find the first pattern that it matches
 V¥                  #  Check that it's the pattern we're looking for
```

Calculating times:

```
Uì60_+60²+XÃÅvu24 gJ,_s ù'02Ã¬ä-
Uì60_                            # Convert the input from base-60 to base-10
     +60²                        # Add 3600, forcing 3 digits of output
         +X                      # Add X minutes
           Ã                     # Convert back to base-60
            Å                    # Remove the extra digit we added
             v                   # Modify the first remaining digit:
              u24                #  Mod 24
                  gJ,_      Ã    # Modify the last digit:
                      s          #  Convert to a string
                        ù'02     #  Left-pad with 0 to length 2
                             ¬   # Join the digits to a string
                              ä- # Get the difference between consecutive digits
```

Check against the patterns:

```
[_e¥0}_e¥J}_ä+ e[TT]}_Î¥ZÌn «Zx}]b!g
                                  !g # Consecutive differences as Z
[                               ]b   # Index of first function that returns true:

 _   }                               #  Index 0: All the same
  e                                  #   Every item in Z
   ¥0                                #   Is 0

      _   }                          #  Index 1: Increasing
       e                             #   Every item in Z
        ¥J                           #   Is -1

           _        }                #  Index 2: Pair
            ä+                       #   Consecutive sums of Z
               e[TT]                 #   Is exactly [0,0]

                     _         }     #  Index 3: Palindrome
                      Î              #   The first item in Z
                       ¥  n          #   Is the opposite of
                        ZÌ           #   The last item in Z
                            «Zx      #   And the sum of Z is 0
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 70 bytes

```
Ｉ⌕ＥＥ﹪⁺↨⁶⁰↨Ｎ¹⁰⁰…⁰φ¹⁴⁴⁰﹪%03d↨¹⁰⁰↨ι⁶⁰⌕⟦⁼⌊ι⌈ι⬤ι∨¬μ⁼λＩ⊕§ι⊖μ⁼⌊⪪ι²⌈⪪ι²⁼ι⮌ι⟧¹Ｎ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVBNa8MwDL3vV4TCQIYM3DT0slP3BTm0K91x7ODGojXITubYpf/es11v7QRCT8/vScj9Udh@EBTC1irj4FlMDt6UkbAW4yUH6WmALfkJnsSEsOR1lUFnRu82Xu/RAqurOecslp0wBwSe@0zM25bHUubM7vlCzsqEKClI1dUyqpM@b/98/faCJlgro7TXoNIEcS44NiuiZHq3sBkc6MgUB9VVPqIzvUWNxqGEleuMxHMyvOCV1uwSf97fbR8jKZfUDbvZe8tePbHf4QltOoKxr3hvevz3NzEeQ2gWTXvXhIcT/QA) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes the time as a 3- or 4-digit string (e.g. `2324`) and maps the categories to `0..3` for same, increasing, pair, palindrome. Explanation:

```
⁺↨⁶⁰↨Ｎ¹⁰⁰
```

Convert the input time into a number of minutes since midnight.

```
﹪...…⁰φ¹⁴⁴⁰
```

Create a range of 1000 minutes starting that that time, and wrapping around at midnight if necessary.

```
Ｅ...﹪%03d↨¹⁰⁰↨ι⁶⁰
```

Convert each time into that range back into a 3- or 4-digit string as appropriate.

```
Ｅ...⌕⟦...⟧¹
```

Find the category of each time, given as the index of the first of these expressions that evaluates to true: ...

```
⁼⌊ι⌈ι
```

... all the digits are the same; ...

```
⬤ι∨¬μ⁼λＩ⊕§ι⊖μ
```

... each digit is one more than the previous; ...

```
⁼⌊⪪ι²⌈⪪ι²
```

... the time is composed of two equal pairs; or...

```
⁼ι⮌ι
```

... the time equals its reverse.

```
Ｉ⌕...Ｎ
```

Find the index of the first time in the desired category.